# Way to obtain numpy array from a .wav sound file in python

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I've tried numerous libraries such as scipy, wavio, wave.. etc and I still don't get the solution.
All I have to do is to get the numpy array from a given sound file.

last one that I tried is scipy, and it doesn't even address the location of the sound file. Can someone recommend me a python library to do my work and some code that can read the .wav file and get the numpy array? 
Thanks

```
import scipy.io.wavfile

rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('sound sample.wav')
sin_data = np.sin(data)

print(sin_data)
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Thats seems to be OK

Comment: *"...it doesn't even address the location of the sound file."*  Please show the complete error message (i.e. the complete traceback).  If you are getting a `FileNotFoundError`, you will have to ensure that  `'sound sample.wav'` is in your current working directory, or give the full path to the file in the filename.   *Any* function that you use to read the wav file will have to be given the correct filename.

Comment: I got the solution. It was just that the first few hundreds of the array was filled with zeros, and the others were correctly converted from the sound file. It was just my mistake that I only saw the print screen at my pycharm and thought it was an error. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following two lines at the beginning of the code:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile
import numpy as np
```